# Payment gateway with "purchase credits/tokens" to integrate in a php+mysql website?

Tags: php, mysql, payment-gateway

Do you know a good payment gateway with "purchase credits" to integrate in a php+mysql website? If is not clear i mean those system where you can buy 50 credits (ala Facebook) and you can spend them playing games or accessing any website restricted content?

is that something that has to be done on my side or the company who sells the gateway does the  complete package?

Comment: I've implemented such a system for a php + mysql site before using PayPal as the payment gateway, and it isn't terribly difficult to do.  Granted, maybe that doesn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payment gateway doesn't care what you're selling. They are only interested in the fund transfers from the card to you.

you'd have to build a system to manage how many credits a user has, how much different 'games' cost in credits, etc. Basically, the payment gate way will ask you "how much do we charge the user?" and when you give them that detail, they'll come back with a "yes, we've charged x amount" You'll then need to write the script to calculate how many credits that equals and assign them to the account.

Paypal is a good cheapie gateway, especially if you don't know what volumes to expect (they don't charge a monthly fee like most of the rest).

Answer (score 0):

PayPal have basic HTML gateways which can send you emails.

Then they also have the more complex IPN system which I have written code for before.

It's not too difficult, and gives you much more power.